# How to make emscripten to emit float.nearest

Tags: c++, floating-point, webassembly

Profiling a large application showed interestingly that more than 5% of the execution time was spent in an external/non-inlined function `roundf`.

I'm only speculating that the corresponding instruction in webassembly could be `f32.nearest`, which is obviously not emitted.

My best workaround has been so far

```
inline int fastRound(float a, float offset = 0.5f) {
     return static_cast<int>(a + offset);
}
```

which allows to use truncation after bringing the value into a positive range (which happens to be the case). This is adequate at best -- and quite bad when needed to work with the negative range as well.

(As an additional compiler flag I've used `-mnontrapping-fptoint` to accept UB for out of range values)

Now the question is, if there's some C++ code that could be interpreted by a moderately recent emscripted / clang compiler to produce the expected bytecode -- or if there's another mechanism like adding webassembly code as inline assembler, or even intercepting the compilation toolchain by forcing a manually created `fastRound` implementation to be inlined by `binaryen`.

Comment: Side note : inline in C++ does not have anything to do with optimization (anymore). It just promises the linker this the one and only definition out there.

Comment: In my framework, I defined `floor_cast`and `ceil_cast` the following way (slightly simplified): `template<std::integral I> I floor_cast(F value) { int64_t w = static_cast<int64_t>(value); return static_cast<I>(w - (value < w)); }
template<std::integral I> I round_cast(F value) { return floor_cast<I>(value + 0.5); }`

Comment: I don't know about web assembly, but on typical hardware my implementation above seems to be the fastest. And also it is correct for all integers. Theoretical drawback: there is a slight bias because of the rounding of *.5 is always up (has never been a problem for me)

Comment: `static_cast<int>(a + 0.5f)` will convert `-1.2` to `0`, which is unlikely what you want. Try `std::lrint(a)` and compile with `-fno-math-errno`.

Comment: Disclaimer: I never used webassembly before and was not aware that this lacks fundamental c++ features (such as `cmath` ...). Clang does provide some `__builtin` functions, which may help you: https://godbolt.org/z/oTx1xv7hY

Comment: @chtz: thanks a lot. Please make it an answer.
The semantics of `f32.nearest` is not what I expected, which is also a valuable information. I'm using `<cmath>` in local build, but godbolt lacks integration to STL headers.

Comment: If there's anything to complain about `return __builtin_nearbyint(a);` it's that this one translates to `frinti s0,s0` -- i.e. using the _current rounding mode_ bringing in some non-determinism for arm64...

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Please feel free to convert this to an answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, one can use clang builtin `__builtin_nearbyint(float)` for the conversion.

In my particular case it turned out, that I actually didn't want that outcome, as against my expectations `0.0f == __builtin_nearbyint(+-0.5f);` (rounding to nearest even).

The method I selected to use generally is close to the other suggested option:

```
int round(float v) {
    v += 0.5f;
    return static_cast<int>(v) - (v <= 0.0f);
}
```

This version omits the conversion from `int` back to `float`, shortening the dependency chain. An alternative would be

```
  return static_cast<int>(v + 0.5f) - (v <= -0.5f);
```

To get `-0.5` rounded to 1, the inequality requires the form `<=` in both of these version.

If one is happy with the bankers rounding, one can also use

```
The int fastRound(float a) {
     return __builtin_rintf(a);
}
        f32.nearest
        i32.trunc_sat_f32_s
```

Using the suggested `__builtin_lrintf(a)` is again suboptimal for webassembly, translating to

```
        local.get       0
        call    lrintf
        end_function
```

Unfortunately it seems, that there's no single C++ code that works optimally  over multiple architectures; for x64, the `lrintf` compiles to `cvtss2si rax, xmm0`, where as the `rintf` compiles to `call    rintf@PLT`.